# How to use only email validation by pattern in AngularJS 1.2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, email-validation

In other words I want to disable angular email validation and use only ng-pattern validation. How I can do it?

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Eq6AFi3MPWLHxXwxHCls?p=preview) (`me&@example.com` need to be valid email address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I decide to use default AngularJS email validation till update to 1.3 version or higher. In higher version I haven't this bug.

Answer (score 2):

replace the type from email to text,

```
<input type="email" .....>
```

by

```
<input type="text" .....>
```

Comment: This solution breaks the semantic structure of page. Is any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Set email to text and regex to this.

```
<input type="text" name="input" ng-model="text" ng-pattern='/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z.]{2,5}$/' required>
```